# Regex - Pattern until double \n

Tags: regex

Somehow I am not able to find anything online about how to set a pattern ending to a double \n. My particular case is the following. I have this string:

```
"1 Matt\n00:00:00,100 --> 00:00:01,500\nThis is said \nby Matt.\n\n2 Lucas\n00:00:01,700 --> 00:00:02,300\nWhile this is said by Lucas"
```

And I would like to extract only the texts between `digit\n` and `\n\n`. So, in my case, I'd like to have

```
This is said \nby Matt.
While this is said by Lucas
```

Although I am not very skilled with RegEx, I tried many combinations such as `?<=\d\n).*?(?=\n\n)`, `?<=\d\n).\n\n` and `?<=\d\n).*?(?=\r\n\r\n)` but without any luck.

I have tried those as well as others with R's `stringr` library, but also with python's `re`.
The issue first came up in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547966/19284124

Comment: Does `(?s)(?<=\d\n).*?(?=\n\n|\Z)` solve the issue?

Comment: You might want to split by double newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `.` match across lines with the `(?s)` inline modifier and extend the double newline pattern to alternatively match the end of string:

```
(?s)(?<=\d\n).*?(?=\n\n|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1tge6/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a flag allowing `.` match line break chars
- `(?<=\d\n)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a digit and a newline
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\n\n|\Z)`  - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with two newline chars or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This regex is more efficient and is a variant that would work on many regex flavors such as Javascript, PHP, Python, java, .NET etc because we avoid using `(?s)` and `\Z` or `\z`:

```bash
(?<=\d\n)(?:.*\n)*?.*(?=\n\n|$)
```

Make sure to use it without `MULTILINE` mode.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBM20H/1)